# gulp-typescript - Issues with Typings

Tags: typescript, gulp, typescript-typings

I am using gulp for compiling my TS files for my frontend. 
Now I need to use some nodejs Stuff inside my TS-Files ('url' and 'process').

For that I installed typings for node. 
When running gulp, my compile task tells me that it can't finde the modules for process and url.

This is my compile task:

```
gulp.task('build:js', function (){
var tsProject = ts.createProject('./tsconfig.json');

return gulp.src('./src/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts(tsProject))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

tsconfig:

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    //"outDir": "dist",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "filesGlob": [
        "typings/index.d.ts"
    ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I couldn't find any example on my own, so I just want you to ask if I have to add Typings to that task or whatelse to do. :)
Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed the global typings for node?

Comment: All typings installed :/